# Choosing std::array template parameters at runtime for limited range of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a templated class that contains an array, and the template arguments are simply the type and length of the array:

```
template<class T, size_t T2> class Sequence {
    /// Attributes ///
    array <T,T2> sequence;

public:
    /// Methods ///
    Sequence();
    Sequence(const Sequence& s);
    // ... more methods that depend on sizeof(T) and sequence.size() exist here
};
```

But I need to be able to choose a combination of T and T2 at run time for a limited range of `size_t k`, such as 4 to 64, so that the total number of bits (`b`) is minimally greater than `2*k` and the number of elements in the array for `b` is minimized.

I understand that I can't simply use a variable in the template argument because then the compiler does not know what is needed at compile time, but it should be possible to compile a sort of mapping from integer k to a few combinations of T and T2.

An example of how the mapping would look:

```
k   T         T2
------------------
8   uint8_t   1
9   uint16_t  1
10  uint16_t  1
11  uint16_t  1
12  uint16_t  1
13  uint16_t  1
14  uint16_t  1
15  uint16_t  1
16  uint16_t  1
17  uint8_t   3
18  uint8_t   3
19  uint8_t   3
20  uint8_t   3
21  uint8_t   3
22  uint8_t   3
23  uint8_t   3
24  uint8_t   3
25  uint16_t  2
26  uint16_t  2
27  uint16_t  2
...
```

The result of this mapping would have to be a class/type that can be easily passed to other templated classes, such as a hashtable which hashes the Sequences depending on their size. My problem is that I can't imagine an implementation of this that would not involve using a variable as a template argument at some point.

To clarify, I need to do something like this, where a single value of k is expected to be used for the entire duration of the program, similar to a global constant.

```
int main(size_t k){
  AbstractSequence<k> s;
  sparse_hash_set <AbstractSequence <k> > k_set;
}
```

The above code isn't possible because k is a variable, but I believe it should be possible for the compiler to statically assert that k is within the accepted range and compile the necessary T/T2 combinations for k=4 to k=64 ...

Comment: What's the benefit of mixing types? Will you actually do something different for `<uint16_t, 1>` than `<uint8_t, 2>` in practice?

Comment: No, but I would like to use the largest data type that is possible to prevent overhead associated with iterating small word sizes.

Comment: So you're confident that iterating over 3 `uint8_t` will always be faster than 2 `uint16_t`, but you don't want to extend this to `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` for higher bit counts. And we don't know what you're doing in this iteration, or how you handle the unused trailing bits. I don't see any real value in changing the type `T` for _storage_, only potentially for _iteration_. Do you really need to conflate the two?

Comment: The table is abridged, i just didn't write it out for the whole series... The word size is secondary to the requirement that the total number of bits in the array does not greatly exceed the length of the sequence, k

Comment: My question is more about how to get around the static limitation of templating.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t T2>
struct Sequence {
    Sequence(const std::vector<bool>& v);
};

template<typename Seq>
void f(Seq sequence);

void dynamic_dispatch(const std::vector<bool>& v) {
    if (v.size() <= 8) {
        f(Sequence<uint8_t, 1>(v));
    } else if (v.size() <= 16) {
        f(Sequence<uint16_t, 1>(v));
    } else if (v.size() <= 24) {
        f(Sequence<uint8_t, 3>(v));
    } else if (v.size() <= 32) {
        f(Sequence<uint16_t, 2>(v));
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unexpected vector size");
    }
}
```

However, you can also do recursive meta-programming. It goes like this:

```cpp
template<size_t k_bound>
void dynamic_dispatch_helper(const std::vector<bool>& v) {
    if (v.size() > 8 * k_bound) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unexpected vector size");
    }
    if (v.size() > 8 * (k_bound - 1)) {  // Recursion stop condition
        f(Sequence<uint8_t, k_bound>(v));  // Simplified T, T2 - can be adapted.
    } else {
        dynamic_dispatch_helper<k_bound - 1>(v); // Recursion!
    }
}

void dynamic_dispatch(const std::vector<bool>& v) {
    dynamic_dispatch_helper<8>(v);
}
```

I think it's scary for humans and it's probably not so good for the compiler's inlining logic, so I wouldn't.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, can you clarify what is the role of the vector<bool> in your example? Since I believe my question may not have been exact enough about the requirements, I have also updated it.